# Showing that $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}: \mathbb{C} \setminus\ ]-\infty, 0] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, solution-verification

(To be clear, $]-\infty,0]$ here means $(-\infty,0]$.) As the title states, I want to show that $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}: \mathbb{C} \setminus\ ]-\infty, 0] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, with
$$\tag{1}
\forall z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash]-\infty, 0]:(\sqrt[3]{\cdot})^{\prime}(z)=\frac{1}{3} \cdot\frac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{z})^{2}}
$$
If I show that $(\sqrt[3]{z})^2\ne0$, then I know that the derivative exists. So consider
$$\tag{2}
(\sqrt[3]{z})^{2}=\left(|z|^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{i \theta}{3}}\right)^{2}=|z|^{\frac{2}{3}} e^{i \theta \frac{2}{3}}
$$
Since we consider $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash]-\infty, 0]$, we know that $|z|\ne 0$ and for any $\theta$ we know that
$\Re\{e^{i \theta \frac{2}{3}}\}+\Im\{e^{i \theta \frac{2}{3}}\}\ne 0$. Therefore, the derivative exists for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash]-\infty, 0]$, and thus $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ is holomorphic. Is this a correct and sufficient proof?

Comment: Why do you state “If I show that $\left(\sqrt z\right)^2\ne0$, then I know that the derivative exists”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, see eq. $(1)$, keeping in mind that $\sqrt[3]{z}$ is continuous.

Comment: The derivative is defined in eq. $(1)$. If $\sqrt[3]{z}^2\ne 0$, then $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z}^2}$ exists.

Comment: No, $(1)$ does *not* defined the derivative. It asks you to *prove* that the derivative is a certain expression.

Comment: I understood that eq. $(1)$ was given, and that the task was to then show that the function is holomorphic. But maybe I might have misunderstood.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, So if I show eq. $(1)$ then it follows from the fact that $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z}^2}$ is continuous that the function is holomorphic, correct?

Comment: No. If you show that the equality $(1)$, then you shall have proved that the given function is holomorphic. The fact that it has a continuous derivative is not relevant.

Comment: A good starting point would be to *define* $\sqrt[3]z$.

Comment: I guess the following is a proof of eq. $(1)$:
$(\sqrt[3]{z})^{\prime}=\left(|z|^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{\frac{i \theta}{3}}\right)^{\prime}=\left(z^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{\prime}=\frac{1}{3} z^{\frac{1}{3}-1}=\frac{1}{3} z^{-\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}\left(z^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{-2}=\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt[3]{z})^{-2}$.
However, continuousness means that the limit tends to the same value for any $z$ - why is that not relevant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136828/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-hydrogen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: just use the definition of $\sqrt[3]{z}$! Its defined as

$$
\sqrt[3]{z}:=z^{1/3}:=e^{\frac1{3}\log z}
$$

Therefore $\sqrt[3]{z}$ will be holomorphic at least as far as $\log z$ is holomorphic, because composition of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.